# Cannot use make function in Cygwin , it just says no module found called "numpy"

Tags: python, numpy, cygwin

I already installed numpy, and i have anaconda 3, but for some reason it doesnt get recognized by Cygwin.

**ERROR CYGWIN LOG**:

```
    $ make
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/cygdrive/c/py-faster-rcnn/lib/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        import numpy as np
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
    make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1

*
```

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin `python` looks only on Cygwin packages.
Install the proper `python3X-numpy` package. With `X` 7, 8 or 9.

I suggest to use python3.9 but you can also stick to python3.8.

Comment: Downloaded the 3.9 numpy version and it did worked but it stated that i still lack packages?

ERROR CYGWIN LOG:                                           $ make
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
   import winreg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1

Comment: what exactly are you trying to install ? https://pypi.org/search/?q=winreg does not show a clear module.